# Mount password protected network drive via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I try to mount network drive by using this command

```
New-PSDrive –Name “C” –PSProvider FileSystem –Root “\\re\Pro\Al\A\V Machines\Vagrant machines” –Persist
```

But when you mount this drive it asks you to enter your domain name and password.

I tried to use this command:

```
New-PSDrive -Name "P" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root “\\re\Pro\Al\A\V Machines\Vagrant machines” -Credential user\domain -Persist
```

And now I see modal window where I see two field, and "Password" field is empty.

Is there any ability to mount drive automatically by using credentials (I have username and password)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the credentials to the new-drive by putting them into a pscredential object.

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString “PlainTextPassword” -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (“username”, $secpasswd)
New-PSDrive –Name “P” –PSProvider FileSystem –Root “\\re\Pro\Al\A\V Machines\Vagrant machines” –Persist -Credential $mycreds
```

You might consider saving the credential set in a locally encrypted file (not the best but better than plaintext) if you plan on using this in a saved script.

Link > [Use current Powershell credentials for remote call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27280655/use-current-powershell-credentials-for-remote-call/27281041#27281041)

Comment: Trey, thanks for suggestion. For now I can even user login and password non-ecnrypted because I have special one for test. 

So should I use something like this

New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (“username”, "password") | New-PSDrive –Name “P” –PSProvider FileSystem –Root “\\repin\Project\AllUA\OrthoSystem\Daily Build\Release 2015\x64” –Persist -Credential

?

Comment: The password must be a secure string in the credential object.  It is the same if you had to type in the credentials into the windows prompt, it would mask the string you type in.  If you have a requirement to fit it into one line it would work to do something like this. `New-PSDrive –Name “P” –PSProvider FileSystem –Root “\\re\Pro\Al\A\V Machines\Vagrant machines” –Persist -Credential $(New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (“username”, $(ConvertTo-SecureString “PlainTextPassword” -AsPlainText -Force)))`

Comment: Yeeeeah, Trey it works like a charm! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to hear Mikhail.  If this worked for you I'd appreciate it if you'd mark the answer as correct.  Thanks!

Comment: Done, Trey. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

An other Option would be to add your Credentials to the Windows Vault:

```
#######################################
#Variables:
$target = <domain>
$user = <username>
$Password = <Password>
#######################################
If($Password) 
{ 
    [string]$result = cmdkey /add:$target /user:$UserName /pass:$Password 
} 
Else 
{ 
    [string]$result = cmdkey /add:$target /user:$UserName  
} 
If($result -match "The command line parameters are incorrect") 
{ 
    Write-Error "Failed to add Windows Credential to Windows vault." 
} 
ElseIf($result -match "CMDKEY: Credential added successfully") 
{ 
    Write-Host "Credential added successfully." 
} 
#######################################################
```