# Remote PowerShell With Task Scheduler Fails Without Desktop Session

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, qlikview

I am trying to execute a remote process with PowerShell, and my trials have led to using Task Scheduler as well.

I need to call an application with an argument. FYI, the application is QlikView Desktop, and its executable is `Qv.exe`. I have not added the application's directory to the host's executable path, so I need to either specify the full patth to the application or change to the application's directory.

First, I tried the following command:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName <hostname> -ScriptBlock {powershell.exe -command "&'C:\Program Files\QlikView\Qv.exe' C:\Qlik\DailyUpdate.qvw /r"}
```

The result was that  - according to the list of running processes on the host - the QlikView application started but did nothing (CPU at 0%) until the process was killed. This failure struck me as a permissions issue, perhaps related to credentials being passed over multiple hops, and I tried a number of ways to pass credentials before I decided to use Task Scheduler to run the nested PowerShell task contained within the above parent PowerShell command's `ScriptBlock` parameter.

So next, I created a Task Scheduler job and, and then I tried the following command:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName <hostname> -ScriptBlock {Schtasks.exe /Run /TN "RunQVDUpdate"}
```

The result was that this commmand works when run from my dev box, when I am logged into the remote host via RDP, but it fails without a desktop session - similar to my first result, the remote application starts but remains idle until manually killed.

I want to figure out the initial issue and fully understand how to properly pass credentials with PowerShell, if that's what it is. Otherwise, I read the following post related to Excel automation, which suggests creating a couple of directories to run Excel non-interactively: https://superuser.com/questions/579900/why-cant-excel-open-a-file-when-run-from-task-scheduler

I'm wondering that if not related to access - permissions or credentials - maybe I need to understand whether the QlikView application needs a temporary directory that is only created with an active desktop session.

Am I dealing with a credentials issue, i.e. double-/multi-hop? Or, is there some set of directories that Windows creates with a desktop session that I need to manually create?

Comment: 1) You don't need  `Invoke-Command` if you're just running `schtasks.exe` with the `/Run` parameter. You can use `/S` (see `schtasks /Run /?` for more information). 2) Only the developer of `Qv.exe` can tell you whether what you want to do is supported. 3) This is probably a superuser rather than a stackoverflow question.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart 1) I need to initiate this process as part of another process on another remote host - do I not need Invoke-Command to establish the remote connection? Task Scheduler in the second command is a workaround for powershell.exe failure in the first command. 2) I haven't found a definitive answer in documentation. 3) Mods can feel free to move the post if they see fit.

Comment: Maybe this would work for you?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27280655/use-current-powershell-credentials-for-remote-call/27281041#27281041