# Invoke-Command Import-Certificate Access Denied

Tags: powershell

Everyone in my network has read access to an SMB share containing a certificate which needs to be installed. I am also executing this code as domain admin.  What is necessary to overcome this error?

```
Access is denied. 0x80070005 (WIN32: 5 ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
```

This is the code where I want to install the certificate on each server.

```
$vms = "App1","App2","App3"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $vms -ScriptBlock {
    Import-Certificate `
        -FilePath \\dc1\CertificateShare\17C37D0A655B89967398C9E7E8185F78541B1589.cer `
        -CertStoreLocation 'Cert:\LocalMachine\Root'

}
```

Comment: "*What is necessary to overcome this error?*" - fixing the the double-hop authentication issue; possible duplicate of [Powershell Server Network drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24903878/powershell-server-network-drive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You run into an issue known as the double hop issue. In essense you are asking the remote session to access another external resource using the same windows authentication.

Microsoft doesn't allow this by default for security reasons.

[image: Double hop issue]

If you want to read more about it, please read the my entire post [PowerShell remoting caveats](https://sarafian.github.io/2016/07/05/remoting-caveats.html)

The solution is not easy and definetely not unique because it primarily has to do with Kerberos authentication and how the domain controller wants to control this. For example the domain controller could specify that a specific double hop is allowed between two servers, or you will have to allow the double hop per server.

The better solution is with domain configuration but you need to get in touch with your domain administrator and convince him.

I'll show by script references how to do this per server. For example from the above picture we must configure `ServerA` to allow credential delegation to `ServerB`.

I had to solve these issues for an automation repository I've build. The automation is named [ISHBootstrap](https://github.com/Sarafian/ISHBootstrap) and I'll refer to scripts from this repository. Not everything fits here. Keep in mind that all scripts can executely locally or remotely and that's why you will notice the use of a wrapper cmdlet for `Invoke-Command` [Invoke-CommandWrap](https://github.com/Sarafian/ISHBootstrap/blob/master/Source/Cmdlets/Helpers/Invoke-CommandWrap.ps1). Just looks into the respected script blocks and extract the code.

First we need to install a couple of pre-requisites on `ServerA`.

I use this script [Install-WinRMPrerequisites.ps1](https://github.com/Sarafian/ISHBootstrap/blob/master/Source/Server/WinRM/Install-WinRMPrerequisites.ps1) but it is as easy as this command

```
Get-WindowsFeature |Where-Object -Property Name -EQ "WinRM-IIS-Ext"|Add-WindowsFeature
```

Then we need to enable and configure WSManCredSSP. This requires an secure remoting session and that's why we need to setup winrm over ssl. This script runs the entire process [Enable-WSManCredSSP.ps1](https://github.com/Sarafian/ISHBootstrap/blob/master/Source/Server/WinRM/Enable-WSManCredSSP.ps1)

1. Enable WSManCredSSP.
2. Install a self signed certificate and configure WSMan with a secure endpoint.
3. Restart WSMan.
4. Open firewall port.

Here is the code extracted from the script:

```
#region Enable WSManCredSSP
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server -Force | Out-Null
#endregion

#region Configure a secure WinRMListener
$winRmListeners=& winrm enumerate winrm/config/listener
$httpsLine= $winRmListeners -match "HTTPS"
Write-Debug "httpsLine=$httpsLine"
if(-not $httpsLine)
{
    $certificate=Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My |Where-Object -Property Thumbprint -EQ $Thumbprint
    $hostname=(($certificate.Subject -split ', ')[0] -split '=')[1]
    Write-Debug "Adding winrm https listener"
    & winrm create winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS  "@{Hostname=""$hostname"";CertificateThumbprint=""$Thumbprint""}"
    Write-Verbose "Added winrm https listener"

    Write-Debug "Configuring ACL"
    # Specify the user, the permissions and the permission type
    $permission = "NETWORK SERVICE","Read,FullControl","Allow"
    $accessRule = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList $permission;

    $keyPath = $env:ProgramData + "\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys\";
    $keyName = $certificate.PrivateKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.UniqueKeyContainerName;
    $keyFullPath = Join-Path $keyPath $keyName;

    # Get the current acl of the private key
    # This is the line that fails!
    $acl = Get-Acl -Path $keyFullPath;

    # Add the new ace to the acl of the private key
    $acl.AddAccessRule($accessRule);

    # Write back the new acl
    Set-Acl -Path $keyFullPath -AclObject $acl;
    Write-Verbose "Configured ACL"
}
else
{
    Write-Warning "winrm https listener detected. Skipped"
}
#endregion

#region restart WinRm service
Write-Debug "Restarting winrm service"
Get-Service -Name WinRM |Restart-Service| Out-Null
while((Get-Service -Name WinRM).Status -ne "Running")
{
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
}
Write-Verbose "Restarted WINRM service"
#endregion


#region Configure windows firewall
$ruleName="WinRM-HTTPS"
$rulePort=5986
Write-Debug "Querying if firewall port for winrm https is open"
if(-not (Get-NetFirewallRule|Where-Object {($_.DisplayName -eq $ruleName) -and ($_.Direction -eq "Inbound")}))
{
    Write-Verbose "Adding firewall port for winrm https is open"
    New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName $ruleName -Direction Inbound -Action Allow -Protocol "TCP" -LocalPort $rulePort|Out-Null
}
Write-Host "Winrm https firewall port is ok"        
#endregion
```

At this point the `ServerA` is ready to delegate your authorization to another server but the client still needs to explicitly state that the remoting session must be capable of this. Create a session like this

```
$session=New-PSSession -ComputerName $Computer -Credential $Credential -UseSSL -Authentication Credssp
```

Notice two important things when using `CredSSP` authentication type:

- `-Credentials` must be explicitly specified even if they are for the same user that is logged on.
- Use `-UseSSL` to use winrm secure.

Now use the `$session` with your original code and it should work

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $vms -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    Import-Certificate `
        -FilePath \\dc1\CertificateShare\17C37D0A655B89967398C9E7E8185F78541B1589.cer `
        -CertStoreLocation 'Cert:\LocalMachine\Root'

}
```